# Retrieving bash's output history

Tags: linux, bash, history

I am using Mac OSX and I am looking for a command that retrieves the history of the outputs (when they exist) of the commands that I ran. Is it possible ?

Comment: The output history doesn't exist. You can use `script` (it's the name of the program) to save both terminal input and terminal output of a particular interactive process (and its children).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Bash only keeps a history of the commands you entered. You can retrieve it by entering 'history'. But I don't think that Bash stores the output of these commands anywhere, this would have to be a feature of your terminal emulator.